# Accessing a pi 4 router's localhost

Tags: networking, access-point, hotspot, web-interface

OK, I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running a router so I can have a SSH for any files on the go.

So (router)--------eth0--------(Pi 4 Access Point/ssh) --------wlan0------- (my device)

I have tools that use php to host a web interface, my issue is I don't know php at all and when I run those tools on localhost I cant access them from the access point made by the Pi.

I want to take the localhost of the pi and forward it to the access point, so I can use it from any device

Here is what I'm using
The Pi4 Access Point software https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui
Latest Raspbian Lite (no desktop)

I know I'm bad at asking on forums, but I need the help. Thanks!

Comment: *take the localhost of the pi and forward it* makes no sense - yu just need your *server* software to *listen* on IP address of  wlan0

Comment: @JaromandaX Forward was probably the wrong way to put it. I just need to be able to access it from the AP. But i dont know what config to edit, or what to put into php